# How to secure a string from XSS?

Tags: java, xss

I basically had my research about this Issue. And I found this tutorial https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/anti-cross-site-scripting-xss-filter.html Which looks quite useful. So I extracted the important parts that I need which is:

```
public String stripXSS(String value) {
    if (value != null) {
       value = value.replaceAll("", "");
       Pattern scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("<script>(.*?)</script>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
       value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");
       scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("src[\r\n]*=[\r\n]*\\\'(.*?)\\\'", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
       value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

       scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("src[\r\n]*=[\r\n]*\\\"(.*?)\\\"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
       value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

       scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("</script>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
       value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

       scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("<script(.*?)>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
       value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");
       scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("eval\\((.*?)\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
       value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");
       scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("expression\\((.*?)\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
       value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

       scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("javascript:", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
       value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

       scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("vbscript:", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
       value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

       scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("onload(.*?)=", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
       value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");
  }
return value;
}
```

Then I'm calling it this way:

```
String filthy = "<h1>Need to secure this.</h1>";
String clean = stripXSS(filthy);
```

Don't know what am I missing but this didn't worked.
I would really appreciate if you could guide me to the right path.

Comment: Didn't work is not a working problem description when asking for help.

Comment: @GhostCat Do you know any alternative to secure a string from XSS?

Comment: You are not explaining what didn't work exactly. How could we help with that. Doctors, me sick cure me?!

Comment: @GhostCat Nice example. See this doesn't gives me no errors but when I send this to the front-end, there it's compiled as an html `<h1>` tag not as a simple text. That's the problem.

Comment: Step back. Write a super simple program that just takes some hard coded example input and that applies one transformation. If that works, try the next rule. If not solve that one small problem. And then the next one.

Comment: Please note that whatever you do, this method is inadequate against XSS in the general case. While input filters can help mitigate some risks and they work against some attack vectors (exactly the ones that you blacklist), preventing XSS this way is pretty much hopeless. In general, any blacklist filter will have ways around it.

Answer (score 0):

This function doesn't attempt to remove heading tags. Probably because they don't involve JavaScript. But it also doesn't remove obvious attributes that do involve JavaScript such as "onmouseover". It also misses basic anti-XSS evasion techniques. So that function is unusable.

A better resource is: [OWASP XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

This focuses more on escaping data on output, based on the surrounding context. The idea of securing a string doesn't really work because what's insecure depends on how its used. Newlines need to be escaped in headers, spaces need to be escaped in command parameters. It also corrupts valid data. Apostrophes can appear in names, but are meta-characters in SQL queries.